# HTTP Get request to Challonge returns robots.txt

Tags: java, json, rest

When sending a get request to try and retrieve a challonge bracket, I get the robots.txt file instead of the actual bracket. If I copy and paste the same url into my browser, I get the intended JSON bracket. I was wondering what I was doing wrong and how I could make it so that the following Java method actually returns the bracket instead of the metaname=robots text file.

```
public String httpGett(String url,String userAgent) throws Exception{
    String USER_AGENT = userAgent;
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    //System.out.println(response.toString());
    return(response.toString());
}
```

For example, if the url I sent was

https://challonge.com/api/tournaments/example.json?include_matches=1&include_participants=1&api_key=[MY
API KEY]

And I typed the url into my browser I would get:
http://pastebin.com/4W4kmdJV

And if I used my Java method to send the get request I would get:
http://pastebin.com/ifYSSzu3

How can I get the correct bracket info from my Java method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I managed to figure out what I was doing wrong, kind of.

When I use:
https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/example.json?include_matches=1&include_participants=1&api_key=[MYAPIKEY]

Instead of the previous link, the metaname=robots link stopped appearing and I got the correct bracket information.